# Encrypted string not being stored in database correctly

Tags: c#, string, encryption, salt

I'm doing some encryption tasks in C# and ran into an issue I can't quite figure out. I sometimes get very complex salted hash strings for users passwords and these strings, for some reason, aren't getting stored in the database correctly.

I'm using an 8-byte salt randomly generated from the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class. I am using the `SHA256Managed` class as my `HashAlgorithm`. I'm getting the string to store from the bytes created via the `ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString()` method. The column these values are being stored in is of type `(NVARCHAR(50), NULL)`. I'm storing them using the `SqlCommand` class.

I can see the exact string fine when stepping through my code and using the immediate window. It seems like the problem is happening when I call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Should I be doing it differently than below?

```
string query = @"UPDATE User SET password = @password WHERE id = @userID";

cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", encryptedPassword);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userID);

int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you require any further information, let me know. I just don't wanna put too much on here about my exact algorithm or the results of it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you converting it to `hex` or `base64` after hash?

Comment: Encoding.Default.GetString Is *not* how you represent arbitrary Bytes as a string. You need to use base-n, such as hex (base-16) or base-64. Or better: store it in a varbinary column instead. BTW, hashing != encryption

Comment: Oh, and ASCIIEncoding.Default is not actually ASCII; that is actually the static Encoding.Default - the local system's default ansi codepage. But it doesn't matter because you can't use **any** Encoding to do what you want here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using                 `Convert.ToBase64String()` instead for encoding byte array into string. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Woah! Thanks! That did the trick!! How is that different from ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString()? It worked, I just don't know why.

Comment: @aladd04 because you are using Encoding in the wrong direction: see http://tiny.cc/io where I discuss this (and other topics)

Comment: What do you mean by "encoding in the wrong direction"? I will check out this article... maybe the answer is in there :) haha.

Comment: @aladd04 Encoding transforms arbitrary text <---> formatted bytes; you don't have formatted bytes - you have arbitrary bytes. For that, you want base-n: base-n transforms arbitrary bytes <---> formatted text

Comment: Ah, I see. That would make sense. I had that confused. Thanks for the information!